# awk send email if

Tags: bash, awk, email

With the following litte awk script, I get an email notification.
But I want to get this email **only** if `$1` is greater or equal than 100.

At which position must I put the if statement? I tried many versions without success. Following my script:

```
awk '

BEGIN{print "Subject:SASL Spam\nFrom:Server.de <test@emailer.com>\nTo:test@emailer.com"}

END{printf("%s\015\n", $1" | "$2)}

' /home/web0/html/tools/uptime/sasl.txt | /usr/lib/sendmail -t test@emailer.com
```

Comment: please give us some example of what is in `/home/web0/html/tools/uptime/sasl.txt` so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: 36 sasl_username=web39p2     66 sasl_username=web57p1
     78 sasl_username=web117p1

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this (I shortened it a bit for readabillity):

```
{ awk 'BEGIN{...} END{...} END{if($1<100){exit(1)}}' file || exit; } > >(sendmail -t ...)
```

- `awk` is called in a [compound command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

  - `if($1<100)` checks for the value
  - `exit(1)` aborts further execution of code inside `awk` and returns the exit code 1
- `|| exit` this is executed when the `awk` command returns false (exit code higher than 0). The shell is then exited and no more commands are executed. I don'0t use the pipe `|` here because that will open a subshell and this subshell is then exited and the next command is executed anyway.
- `>(sendmail -t ...)` the output is sent to `sendmail` (if not yet exited).

---

The whole command would then look like:

```
{ awk 'BEGIN{print "Subject:SASL Spam\nFrom:Server.de <test@emailer.com>\nTo:test@emailer.com"}
  END{printf("%s\015\n", $1" | "$2)} END{if($1<100){exit(1)}}' \
/home/web0/html/tools/uptime/sasl.txt || exit; } > >(/usr/lib/sendmail -t test@emailer.com)
```

Comment: This will also send a mail when `awk` fails when one of the parameters is incorrect. For example is `$1` is equal to "TEST".

Comment: @Marco No when awk fails the part after `||` is executed, hence no email. And when $1 equals TEST it's no greater or equal than 100...

Comment: still always sending notification. 
Email body is "78 - sasl_username=web117p1" 
It makes no differce: $1>=100 or $1>=9999

Comment: @MichaelWoldrich Sorry, the statement was wrong: I had `$1>=100` instead of `$1<100`. Please try again, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

So this uses a single awk statement to prepare an email containing data only from the lines in the source file start with a number >=100, if none of them meet this condition then no email is sent, which is I think what you are trying to achieve. It also makes sure that the first field is numeric in case there is some unexpected text there which might confuse the numeric comparison:

```
awk '
{
  if ($1~/^[0-9]*$/ && $1>=100) {
    if (BEENHERE!=1) print "Subject:SASL Spam\nFrom:Server.de <test@emailer.com>\nTo:test@emailer.com\n"
    printf("%s\015\n", $1" | "$2); BEENHERE=1
  }
}' /home/web0/html/tools/uptime/sasl.txt  | \
/usr/lib/sendmail -t test@emailer.com
```